# Nikola: Adding a link with an id

Tags: html, nikola

I'm a newbie at Nikola, editing an existing site. There's an `rst` file that gets compiled to HTML. I want to add this to the HTML:

```
<a id="floof" href="floof.html">
    Bigtime floof
    <img src="floof.jpg">
</a>
```

What code do I need to add on the `rst` side to have it output the HTML above?